# How to deployment via AWS DeployCode?

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment

After create deployment in detail alway show Minimum healthy hosts: 0 of 1 instances.

And after few minutes show error code: [HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/console/codedeploy/ecode_health_constraints).

I do not understand where to look?

Instance is a fine working.

Comment: I do not understand why the minus for the question, even if they can not explain it? If you do not know the answer, then it's better to pass by, and if you know the solution, be kind, write the answer or give a link to the solution of the question. I hate stupid people who place minuses, while not commenting on their position in any way.

Comment: How have you configured the system for health checking? Your healthy host count comes from your health-check configuration. If your using an ELB and autoscaling your health checking parameters will be defined as part of the ELB and the autoscaling group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolve my problem in the AWS forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=584053#584053

If use old instance with other IAM profile, then after change IAM profile for CodeDeploy it was necessary to restart instance.